# Illustrator: All artwork has jagged edges after changing settings

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I rasterized a logo (plus made other changes I can't quite remember), a few days ago and ever since then my logo is jagged and distorted.

Even though I didn't save whatever effect I applied, all my artwork now doesn't look as it should.

[Here's how it looks now](http://bit.ly/1beP4RJ) and [here's how it looked then](http://bit.ly/1iRb496).

I've deleted the AIPrefs file, the whole CS5 settings folder and it's not anti aliasing or pixel preview.

Is there another way to completely restore it to factory defaults?  Whatever change I made the other day seems to be affecting everything since.

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: To be clear... "I rasterized a logo" is the file raster or not. I realize you said you did not save any effects, but did you save it as a rasterized version?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have inadvertently changed your View Mode to "Pixel Preview."

Look under the View pulldown menu to see whether or not "Pixel Preview" is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yeah I checked that too, sorry I forgot to mention. I'll update the question.